# With Rx, How to get the latest value per unique key?

Tags: system.reactive

How to get the latest value per unique key?

In this sample, I have stock ticker and price. How do I combine it such that it will output unique stocks with the latest price?

In real life, this stream of events will keep running for years and I only need the current price of a stock.

```
using System;
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace LearnRx
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Stock
        {
            public string Symbol { get; set; }
            public float Price { get; set; }
            public DateTime ModifiedAt { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return "Stock: " + Symbol + " " + Price + " " + ModifiedAt;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var baseTime = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
            var fiveMinutes = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            var stockEvents = new Stock[]
            {
                new Stock
                {
                    Symbol = "MSFT",
                    Price = 100,
                    ModifiedAt = baseTime
                },
                new Stock
                {
                    Symbol = "GOOG",
                    Price = 200,
                    ModifiedAt = baseTime + fiveMinutes
                },
                new Stock
                {
                    Symbol = "MSFT",
                    Price = 150,
                    ModifiedAt = baseTime + fiveMinutes + fiveMinutes
                },
                new Stock
                {
                    Symbol = "AAPL",
                    Price = 300,
                    ModifiedAt = baseTime + fiveMinutes + fiveMinutes + fiveMinutes
                },
            }.ToObservable();

            var scheduler = new HistoricalScheduler();
            var replay = Observable.Generate(
                stockEvents.GetEnumerator(),
                events => events.MoveNext(),
                events => events,
                events => events.Current,
                events => events.Current.ModifiedAt,
                scheduler);


            replay
                .Subscribe( i => Console.WriteLine($"Event: {i} happened at {scheduler.Now}"));

            scheduler.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a marble diagram of what you want? If you're always interested in the latest price... it's just the latest event.

Comment: The output of the above code has 4 entries, expected is 3. There should only be one output for MSFT.

Comment: “In real life, this stream of events will keep running for years and I only need the current price of a stock.” At any given moment, the most recent event is the current price. Do you want to emit all events? In the test case there’s an end, in real life there isn’t.

Comment: Say I want to get the count of stocks above $90, the above code will return 4 instead of 3 because it will double count MSFT. It is like I need a combineLastest which takes a key, in this case stock symbol. 
stocks.CombineLastest(r => r.Symbol).Where(r => Price > 99)

Comment: As a developer that actually does this in his day job, I suggest you think about using `IDictionary<Stock, IObservable<Price>>` rather than `IObservable<IDictionary<Stock, Price>>`. The later makes it hard to remove Stocks from your subscription...

Comment: @Aron, I was curious about how items are removed too. A vanilla solution is to update a record in a database for every event and I don’t have to worry about Dictionary running out of memory. The problem with introducing a DB is, something will have to scan the DB to get all stocks that meet a criterion and there are many such rules. These rules depend on aggregated data which is why I need to see the latest state of a stock before running aggregations. If a stock is delisted, it must be removed from the process.

Comment: I am not sure if I can use Rx for this purpose or if I should just stick with a traditional database approach.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't advise you on which is better. My world, we use RX because we have millisecond latency requirements. Databases are slow by design (ACID). You should also decide based on familiarity with the tech, you obviously are more comfortable with RDBMS over RX. So really it comes down to, "is learning RX worth the performance?".

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a `GroupBy` followed by a `CombineLatest` that should exist, but doesn't.

Here's the missing `CombineLatest`:

```
public static class X
{
    
    public static IObservable<ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue>> CombineLatest<TKey, TValue>(this IObservable<IGroupedObservable<TKey, TValue>> source)
    {
        return source
            .SelectMany(o => o.Materialize().Select(n => (Notification: n, Key: o.Key)))
            .Scan(default(Notification<ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue>>), (stateNotification, t) => {
                var state = stateNotification?.Value ?? ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Empty;
                switch(t.Notification.Kind) {
                    case NotificationKind.OnError:
                        return Notification.CreateOnError<ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue>>(t.Notification.Exception);
                    case NotificationKind.OnCompleted:
                        return Notification.CreateOnNext(state.Remove(t.Key));
                    case NotificationKind.OnNext:
                        return Notification.CreateOnNext(state.SetItem(t.Key, t.Notification.Value));
                    default:
                        throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            })
            .Dematerialize();
    }
}
```

And then here's the final query in `Main`:

```
var prices = replay
    .GroupBy(s => s.Symbol)
    .CombineLatest()
```

This will give you an `Observable<Dictionary<string, Stock>>` for each price point. This should enable you to do whatever downstream.

Comment: Nice. It is getting the latest event. Using a dictionary with upsert was a solution I was thinking about.  The code does have an interesting output. I understand the output till iteration #4 but after that, why is the items going away one by one?

#1 
Dic count 1
MSFT     100 
#2
Dict count 2
GOOG     200
MSFT     100 
#3
Dict count 2
GOOG     200
MSFT     150
#4
Dict count 3
GOOG     200
MSFT     150
AAPL     300 
#5
Dict count 2
GOOG     200
AAPL     300 
#6
Dict count 1
AAPL     300 
#7
Dict count 0

Comment: The code supports a group ending, mimicking a stock being delisted or something. If one of the child observables ends, it falls out of the dictionary. In the test code, each of the four child observables ends before the parent, creating the output you’re seeing.